# Как восстановить или удержать соединение mqtt?

Tags: python, сокет, asyncio, mqtt

Я использую gmqtt для подключения к сервису, чтобы ловить пуш уведомленя. Все работает нормально, но спустя где то 20 часов работы разрывается соединение. Не могу понять как его восстановить либо удерживать.

Использую gmqtt и asyncio

Вот таким образом открываю подключение:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(listener_worker())
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
```

Вопрос в том, как восстановить подключение после его потери?

Логи:

```
...
2021-02-27T14:22:51.137758390Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
2021-02-27T14:22:51.170936955Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.mqtt.handler:[CMD 0xd0] b''
2021-02-27T14:22:51.171640770Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.mqtt.handler:[PONG REQUEST] 0xd0 b''
...
2021-02-27T14:30:21.140431995Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T14:37:51.142950695Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
2021-02-27T14:37:51.176334802Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.mqtt.handler:[CMD 0xd0] b''
2021-02-27T14:37:51.176967526Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.mqtt.handler:[PONG REQUEST] 0xd0 b''
...
2021-02-27T14:45:21.145039908Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T14:46:58.985163975Z app[web.1]: INFO:gmqtt.mqtt.protocol:[CONN CLOSE NORMALLY]
2021-02-27T14:46:58.985715987Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.mqtt.handler:[CMD 0xe0] b''
...
2021-02-27T14:52:51.146237434Z app[web.1]: WARNING:gmqtt.mqtt.protocol:[TRYING WRITE TO CLOSED SOCKET]
2021-02-27T14:52:51.146868660Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T15:00:21.152518544Z app[web.1]: WARNING:gmqtt.mqtt.protocol:[TRYING WRITE TO CLOSED SOCKET]
2021-02-27T15:00:21.153076405Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T15:07:51.157319919Z app[web.1]: WARNING:gmqtt.mqtt.protocol:[TRYING WRITE TO CLOSED SOCKET]
2021-02-27T15:07:51.157989641Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T15:15:21.162938438Z app[web.1]: WARNING:gmqtt.mqtt.protocol:[TRYING WRITE TO CLOSED SOCKET]
2021-02-27T15:15:21.163468707Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
2021-02-27T15:22:51.169491883Z app[web.1]: WARNING:gmqtt.mqtt.connection:[LOST HEARTBEAT FOR 1800 SECONDS, GOING TO CLOSE CONNECTION]
2021-02-27T15:22:51.170344849Z app[web.1]: DEBUG:gmqtt.client:[KEEP ALIVE]
...
```

Дальше тишина и уведомления не приходят, приходится вручную перезапускать.

Функция подключения:

```
async def connect(self, host, port=1883, ssl=False, keepalive=900):
    # Init connection
    self._host = host
    self._port = port
    self._ssl = ssl
    self._keepalive = keepalive

    self._connection = await self._create_connection(
        host, port=self._port, ssl=self._ssl, clean_session=self._clean_session, keepalive=keepalive)

    await self._connection.auth(self.fbns_auth, will_message=self._will_message,
                                **self._connect_properties)
    await self._connected.wait()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while not await self._persistent_storage.is_empty:
        await loop.create_future()

    if self._error:
        raise self._error
```

Answer (score 0):

После LOST HEARTBEAT будет закрытие соединения. Изучил код - прицепиться некуда. Остается переодически проверять и перезвпускать.

Не вижу реализации listener_worker... но разбей его на 2 части. В одной получи клиента во второй что у тебя там дальше - не знаю)

```
async def main():

    async def watchdog(client, event):
        await client._connected()
        while client.is_connected:
            await  asyncio.sleep(keepalive/2)
        event.set()
    
    event = asyncio.Event()
    await client.connect()

    tasks = [ loop.create_task(t) for t in [watchdog(event), listener_worker()]]
    
    try:
        finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)    
        for t in unfinished:
            t.cancel()
    except:
        asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass
    loop.create_task(main())

loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Я хотел бы задать еще пару вопросов, как можно с тобой связаться?)

Comment: @EduardKumskyi может не надо?)